# Unable to run Optaplanner Webexamples

Tags: optaplanner

I am unable to run OPtaplanner 6.3 on Tomcat 6 or Tomcat 7.

12:23:37,710 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] **Error installing to PostClassLoader: name=vfs:///F:/axaroDev/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6**.x_Runtime_Server1455858893652/deploy/optaplanner-webexamples-6.3.0.Final.war state=ClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PostClassLoader: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfs:///F:/axaroDev/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.x_Runtime_Server1455858893652/deploy/optaplanner-webexamples-6.3.0.Final.war
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]

**Caused by: java.lang.Error: Error visiting "/F:/axaroDev/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.x_Runtime_Server1455858893652/deploy/optaplanner-webexamples-6.3.0.Final.war/WEB-INF/lib/optaplanner-core-6.3.0.Final.jar/org/optaplanner/core/config/score/director/ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.class"**
    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:268) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:409) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:411) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:411) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]

```
... 69 more
```

**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error visiting resource: VFSResourceContext @ org/optaplanner/core/config/score/director/ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.class / BaseClassLoader@63920fcc{vfs:///F:/axaroDev/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.x_Runtime_Server1455858893652/deploy/optaplanner-webexamples-6.3.0.Final.war}**, visitor: org.jboss.scanning.annotations.plugins.GenericAnnotationVisitor@2412ad77
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.IgnoreSetErrorHandler.handleError(IgnoreSetErrorHandler.java:56) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.visit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:91) [:1.0.0.GA]

**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error retrieving annotation attribute values
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.AnnotationValueFactory.createAnnotationValue(AnnotationValueFactory.java:124) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]**
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.createAnnotationValue(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:124) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.getAnnotations(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:117) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl$1.run(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:177) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl$1.run(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:166) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_45]

**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Array component type byte is not handled
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.AnnotationValueFactory.getArray(AnnotationValueFactory.java:220) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]**
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.AnnotationValueFactory.createValue(AnnotationValueFactory.java:61) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.AnnotationValueFactory.createAnnotationValue(AnnotationValueFactory.java:119) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    ... 97 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That specific war file, optaplanner-webexamples 6.3 or higher requires an app server with JAX-RS support, such as WildFly, JBoss EAP, Weblogic, Websphere, ...

OptaPlanner itself (optaplanner-core etc) works perfectly on tomcat, Jetty, etc.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey.. Just a suggestion - Why doesn't the optaplanner team host the examples online somewhere on web ?

Comment: Good point. Because we need to keep that running and that takes a non-trivial amount of time :) I had that webexamples war on openshift, but then it stopped working after 2 months because I hadn't changed from debug logging and our file quota was reached (with a free account). I do intend to set this up again, it would be useful indeed. I first want to flesh out the VRP maps example further.

Comment: oh yea - the vrp maps example, in combination with google maps, uses my free Google API key. That's another problem, as there are quota restrictions on that too...

Comment: Thanks..The bad news is that i have failed to host it successfully on JBoss. I dont have much idea about Jboss and unable to resolve it..
Posted it separately...

Comment: I test it with WildFly 9.0.1.Final regularly, we even got an arquillian test for it.